# Calculate field with IF statement

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-pro

i'm a python beginner. 
I have a table with 4 fields `def_score`, `PA_score`, `GPS_score` and `coop_score`. 
I would like to calculate `coop_score` based on the first 3 fields with the following code block, but it's not working. Where am i wrong?

```
defor = 'def_score'
PA = 'PA_score'
GPS = 'GPS_score'   # GPS values are [1, 1.5, 2]

def calc(coop_score): 
    if PA == 0 and defor == 0: 
        return GPS 
    else: 
        return ((PA + defor) * GPS)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def calc(PA, defor, GPS): #The input fields here, not the output field. The field order need to be the same as when you call the function.
    if PA == 0 and defor == 0: 
        return GPS 
    else: 
        return ((PA + defor) * GPS)
```

Call with coop_score=

```
calc(!PA_score!,!def_score!,!GPS_score!) #You need the actual fieldnames here enclosed in !!
```